# unable to delete span inputbox

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm really new in Javascript...
I'm trying to build list of input text box when user selects option.
However, when user changes option, input text box is created beside previous input text box. Hence, there could be 100 input boxes if user continuously changes option.
I want my program to delete everything in span and generate list of input text boxes.
Please, give me any suggestions!

```
function myInputs() {

        alert('writing inputs'); 
        var value = document.getElementById("name").value; 
        var split = value.split(",");
        var size = split.length;
        var out = document.getElementById("inputBox");
        $(this).parent('display').remove(); //doesn't delete any...
        for (var j=0; j<size; j++){
            if (split[j] != ""){
            var element = document.createElement("input");
            //Assign different attributes to the element.
            element.setAttribute("type", "text");
            element.setAttribute("value", split[j]);
            element.setAttribute("name", split[j]);
            out.appendChild(element);}
      }
};


//html
<table border="0">
<tr>
        <td>Select run : </td>
        <td><select id="name" name="name" onchange="myInputs()">
             <option value="time" name="timer">timer</option>
             <option value="date,time" name="Performance">Performance</option>
             <option value="location,time" name="Copy">Copy</option>
             </select>
        </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <div id="display"><span id = "inputBox"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector doesn't look right, try:

```
$('#display input').remove(); // remove all input's under #display
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used jQuery since you have jQuery code on the page. Below is the corrected jsFiddle

Cache your selectors for speed

```
var $select = $('#name');
var $input = $('#inputBox');
```

I used to do the click handler

```
$select.on("change",function(event){

    $input.empty();

    var value = $select.val().split(",");
    var size = value.length;

    for (var j=0; j<size; j++){
        if (value[j] != ""){
            var element = document.createElement("input");
            element.setAttribute("type", "text");
            element.setAttribute("value", value[j]);
            element.setAttribute("name", value[j]);
            $input.append(element);

            // could also do this but it is slower
            // var $element = $('<input/>',{
            //     type: "text",
            //     name: value[j],
            //     value: value[j]
            // });
            //$input.append($element);
        }
    }                
});
```

I also used the jQuery value function

```
$select.val();
```

You dont want to remove the display because then inputBox is removed and you can no longer access it. So I just used empty on the input box.

```
$input.empty();
```

All of this is also, wrapper in document ready, there are two syntax for this, I use $(function(){}), but its up to you. You have to use document ready so that your elements are in the DOM for querying

Let me know if this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/UR4H8/

Answer (score 1):

You can remove every child with `empty()`. Just call it after selecting the `span` with jQuery

```
var out = $("#inputBox");
out.empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla JavaScript you can simply add `removeChild()` before appending a new element.

with JQuery use the `html()` method, which replaces the existing content rather than appending it.